# Dealer's Choice - What type of games should one choose?

Tags: poker-strategy, home-game

What kind of poker would be hardest for loose pre-flop amateurs to play? Any real game such as 7-stud, PLO-4, PLO-5, Courchevel, 3-Draw, etc, along with made up ones would be accepted.

A made up game could for instance be PLO with an additional street and betting round, or to play PLO with two boards and after the last betting round you take all board cards shuffle them up and lay them out randomly.

This is a matter of psychology and thus behavior of weak players and not about opinion.

If there is a toss up between all types of poker there is and isn't then this would be a matter of opinion. Otherwise there will be an answer that is better then the next one. Or correct me if I'm wrong.

I don't know if the rules allow adding an answer into the question but I'll try that and can edit this later. From my experience it is very good to play two board games since bad players are satisfied to play one of the boards and thus get freerolled a lot. Besides that I'm in vacuum. Some games get tighter when you play 5 or 6 card PLO while some get looser.

Comment: I usually hate it when I have to close questions (especially the ones of newcomers), and this is one of those times. I think there is no clear best answer here and it will end up in a debate. That is why I closed it.

Comment: Not so much that it is opinion based it is simply that what the best games are, are what the poster is best at, so it is not a real question because there is no valid answer. Close it.

Comment: Just so I get this straight, I just saw and answered a question titled "What app for tracking sessions on iPhone?" and the person wanted to know what "good" apps there is out there. So that is more science and fact-based and less about opinions?

Comment: @MacProGirl, as i see it, _apps_ are just easier to pass as a question (although, still very opinion-based questions) rather opinions on game types. If you ask me, i don't like both kind of questions (_what apps.._ and _what game types.._).

Comment: @vlzl, you forgot to mention WHY it should be easier to pass an app question. Opinions are opinions. The reasoning on this site or by the moderators seem very inconsistent. Not a great welcome to this site. I rephrased the question now so let's see what happens.

Comment: @MacProGirl, i'm sorry, you're right i didn't mention the _why_. I believe that apps are easier to pass the test (although, still they should be closed at first), because they tend to be more specific and straight at what they do, they do this and that and users either like them or not, there are _facts_ about them. Game types are more human-based, one have his own views on a gametype, their preferences, their _style_, for example some prefer regular and other turbo poker --you can't answer what's better, it's opinion-based on their _preference_ and/or winrate,

Comment: Most poker apps track the same thing and gives and hourly rate. Besides that they have a few differences which would end up being about personal taste. Maybe someone like the UI better in one app, while another prefer the deeper stats you get from another app. Well, I guess we won't get much further in this discussion so let's forget it.

Comment: I think another part of the problem is that the scope of this question is huge: the universe of poker varieties (plus varieties yet to be invented) and the universe of player types. I think a little discussion/opinion is easier to justify with a more targeted question. If you're instead asking something like how your edge is affected in high-only games versus high-low games against a small set of player types, I think that would work out better. While the app question was somewhat opinion-based, it was definitely way more narrow in scope than this.

Comment: There could be a universe of app to choose from as well. But for most potential answers there won't be a universe of games to select from. Most people have a few in mind and they will answer according to those they know. And the same goes for player types. Even if I wrote 3 LAG and 4 LP player that isn't enough info. Loose pre? Post? There's many variables but still I'm pretty sure those questions have been asked here. Most answers will include wild assumptions and opinions. But nevermind...

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question. Like many questions on here, it's an "against this type of player, how should I get an advantage" question. Answers can only be probabilistically correct.

Comment: Thanks WW! I understand the critique, but if someone doesn't like the question that someone doesn't have to answer. Others can give their speculative answers. The answer is more about how someone should reason than an exact answer since there will never be exact answer with so many unknown variables as always when discussing poker and playing styles.